# PHP: Error when uploading certain file types

Tags: php, file-upload

The code below will make uploading a file in the specified directory.

```
function uploadFile() {
    if ($_POST['dir']) {
        $dir = $_POST['dir'];
    } else {
        alert('warning', 'Directory not chosen!');
        return;
    }

    $uploaddir = getcwd() . $dir;
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        alert('success', 'File uploaded successfully to the directory ' . $dir . '!');
    } else {
        alert('warning', 'Error when uploading!');
    }
}
```

**It works, but only for certain types of files.** Image files such as JPG and PNG sends successfully, however, files like PDF and ICO can not send.

Comment: What does `$_FILES['userfile']['error']` output?

Comment: did you check the file size?

Comment: @VinodVT, the have less than 1mb

Comment: It is pretty difficult to make out from the code that you have put up. You need to show the form where you are getting these values. Just to confirm, files are .jpg and .png are getting uploaded without any problem?

Comment: @Amal Murali, returns "2". Can not find what this value means

Comment: @KeplerBR: A little Googling could always help: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php :)

Comment: Was researching the variable $_FILES...
Well, I'll see how to work around this limit. Tested with larger images and the same error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was extremely easy...

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1073741824" />
```

1073741824 -> 1GB in byte
I forgot that the "value" field is set in byte.